# Getting an ENS error when interacting with a Smart Contract using ethers library

Tags: javascript, solidity

I everyone, I'm trying to call a function called 'safeMint' on an ERC721 contract deployed on Rinkeby testnet but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name (argument="name", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
```

This is the code I'm using to call the function

```
const mintNFT = async () => {
        const {ethereum} = window;
        if(isMetaMaskInstalled) {
            try {
                const abi = require('../contracts/Animals.json').abi;
                console.log(abi);
                const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
    
                setAccount(accounts[0]);
                
                const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
                const signer = web3Provider.getSigner();
                
                const contractWrite = new ethers.Contract('0x53Ea14980c8326E93a9F72889171c1e03d4aD6Ce', abi, signer);
            
                let trx = await contractWrite.safeMint(account, props.cidOfJsonInIpfs);
                console.log(trx);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            
        }
    }
```

I've tried to print the parameters passed but they seem to be right, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the following code

```
   const mintNFT = async () => {
        const {ethereum} = window;
        if(isMetaMaskInstalled) {
            try {
                const abi = require('../contracts/Animals.json').abi;
                console.log(abi);
                const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' });
    
                
                const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
                const signer = web3Provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);
                console.log(signer._address)
                
                const contractWrite = new ethers.Contract('0x53Ea14980c8326E93a9F72889171c1e03d4aD6Ce', abi, signer);
                let trx = await contractWrite.safeMint(accounts[0], `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${props.cidOfFile}`);
                let receipt = await trx.wait();
                console.log(receipt);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            
        }
```

What I was missing: I was using setState function to set the 'account' state variable with the first account of metamask, instead, I started using account[0] directly and it worked!
I will accept this as solution in 2 days